# Need To Understand Transistor Based Led Circuit

Tags: led, transistors, capacitor, resistance, zener

1. Which Transistor Topology Is Used in the Below Circuit & Why?
2. Need to understand the purpose of zener diode (ZD2) with 12.5 Vz and R1 with 2k value?
3. Why C1 & R2 is used for Q1 transistor?

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of this circuit? It appears to be something like a lamp that is intended to operate from either 12V or 24V.

Comment: I'm concerned about the lack of junction dots near R6 and R7.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's be clear that this is a crappy circuit.  Five LEDs in parallel is not a good idea for one thing.

However, the point seems to be that Q1 will be off when the input voltage is "low".  That allows Q2 to be on, which switches in additional parallel LED load resistance.  For low input voltages, the resistance in series with the LEDs is (R24+R25+R34+R35)//(R8+R9+R22+R23).  For high input voltages, Q1 is on so Q2 is off and the LED load resistance is just (R24+R25+R34+R35).

You can think of this circuit as being a two-range current regulator.

Overall it looks quite wasteful and more complicated than it needs to be.  It woul help to know the two zener voltages and acceptable range of input voltage.

Comment: Sounds right. Is C1 meant to prevent Q1 switching on voltage transients while operating on "low" voltage?

Comment: @Rev: Yes, C1 is helps to low pass filter the supply voltage signal, presumably to keep the circuit from reacting to short transients.

Comment: In above circuit,R8-R35 resistor has choose on what basis?? OR  How to decide for resistor quantity & package for such application ?

Comment: @nsuri: I didn't design this circuit, so I can't say how whoever did came up with the values.  We don't even know what the values are.  As I also said, this is a crappy circuit, so I wouldn't assume the values were decided correctly.  Without real numbers, we can't tell.